# How to change url by routing in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Route::get('test','ProfileController@test');
I have above route,while hitting this route in url i see www.example.com/test,
Is it possible to change the url to something.com/test using laravel routing only for this specific route.

Answer (score 1):

`example.com` is your domain, then you need to buy `something.com`
then you need to configure `something.com` that point to your sever that is hosting your laravel application. Then you could do something.com/test.

Remember,

example.com -> translate like XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX IP

something.com -> need to be translated to the same  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX IP

Because `example.com` is the host part and `/test` is the path of your app.

Comment: thankyou for you answer but in my case in example.com there is another application running and something.com is its subdomain. i want to know can we change the whole url name from laravel. like in my case for above route 'test' there will always be in url subdomainname/test,can i change this url to myprofile/test and for other routes it is fine to have route like subdomainname/login etc.

Comment: `Route::group(['prefix'=>'subdomainname'],function(){
 Route::get('test','ProfileController@test');

});`

Comment: I think you could do something like this put on group with a prefix.

Comment: Inside this you could add the login routes and other routes that you like.

Comment: I'm sorry.! Ohh I got it!  see the next answer.. I agree with the wunch solution!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the visible domain part of the url without actually redirecting to that new domain. (Doing so would be a serious security risk.)

If you want to redirect to that other domain (assuming it exists), you can do:

```
// Redirect a route to another URL (note the use of the http://)
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return redirect('http://something.com/test');
});
```

However, if the target is a subdomain or alias of the current domain which is running the same application, then you can do [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing). I like to use named routes:

```
// Define the route on the subdomain
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.example.com', function() {
    Route::get('/test', ['as' -> 'subdomain.test', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@test']);
});

// Redirect a route on the main domain to the subdomain
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return redirect()->route('subdomain.test');
});
```